# How to format old laptop and install CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I have an old laptop with Windows 7. 
I want to remove everything and install CentOS 7 to turn it into a server.

What I know is that I should format the old OS somehow and get iso image of CentOS and make it as bootable usb to install.

Is this what I should do to make it a linux server? 
If I can keep Windows 7, I want to keep it, but how do I have both running in my old laptop?

Comment: This will give you a good start: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-centos-7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambert 's comment (Dedoimedo page) gives you the basics that you need to understand the process of making the Windows partition smaller, and creating a new partition for CentOS in the space newly made available.

As for the process of obtaining the actual system and installing it, then yes, you have it right. To summarize:

1. Download the appropriate ISO image.
2. Either burn it to a blank DVD, or prepare a USB stick from the contents of the ISO.
3. Boot the computer from the DVD or USB stick, and follow the installer program's instructions.

Since this may be the first time you do this, I would suggest going with the blank DVD instead of the USB, it may be more simple if the target computer has a DVD drive available to it. Many DVD burning programs are available to do this. Just make sure you are burning the ISO file as a disk image, and not adding it to a new DVD file structure. Look for an option to "burn an image" in the software you use.